# Importing python modules and extension modules with the same name

Tags: python, python-import, python-module, python-extensions, mypyc

Let's say I built a package with a Python module and an extension module in it, but with the identical name

```
mypackage
|
+-- __init__.py
|
+-- mymodule.py
|
+-- mymodule.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

I have found that when I do `from mypackage import mymodule`, it is the extension module that is being imported. I wonder why this is the case? Does extension modules take precedence during imports? If so, could anyone point to where this behavior is documented?

Answer (score 1):

Check out this [doc](https://www.python.org/doc/essays/packages/) on imports, it includes the following blurb about importing modules with the same name:

> Tip: the search order is determined by the list of suffixes returned by the function imp.get_suffixes(). Usually the suffixes are searched in the following order: ".so", "module.so", ".py", ".pyc"

Comment: Awesome! Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for!